# Umbraco ApiController actions wont map to http-verb

Tags: asp.net-web-api, umbraco, routes, http-verbs

I have been working some with the Web API before.. and as far as I can remember..
The actions in (at least the new version) is called Get,Post,Delete,Put etc...
and these actions are triggered depending of the http-verb in the request..

So for instance you might have an ApiController called UserApiController..

and if you do a request to /api/user with the POST http-verb.. then the Post-action in that controller will be triggered/executed..

However....
it seems like Im having some trouble with this using the UmbracoApiController... for some reason it wont execute post or get or any other action mapped to the http-verb..
Any ideas?.. is there any other way to sort of force a method to be executed depending on the http-verb?

My current code is:

```
public class MyController : UmbracoApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public bool Post()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have placed a breakpoint with in the action..

Comment: Any luck on the issue? Me too facing the same problem. I could be able to hit the controller but i couldn't get values from client to server. Please share if you solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

The reason they won't be accepted is you're using the wrong attribute - `HttpPost` is part of the System.Web.Mvc namespace, whereas Web API is part of the System.Web.Http namespace.
You have to use `AcceptVerbs("POST")` instead.

Comment: after some more reading.. isn't HttpPost just shorthand for AcceptVerbs("POST")?... seems like it.. and my actual problem has nothing to do with that.. since if I create a simple Action-method called Get(), the Get wont be executed during a GET-request.. which does work in the "normal" web api with out any attribute-decorations as far as I know..

Comment: What URL are you using to post to the controller? UmbracoApiControllers map to /umbraco/api/<controller>/<action> so you need to call POST to /umbraco/api/My/Post with your data.